# Azure mobile service .net back end with repository and unit of work pattern

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I want to develop backend server for mobile apps(android,iOS and windows) with azure mobile service(.net). I am looking for a sample project which has repository pattern and unit of work pattern implemented in mobile service.

Till now I have not seen any sample which explains this possibility. If any one has come across then please share a link with me.

I want to implement an enterprise level application architecture with azure mobile service(something like onion architecture) where I can isolated each layer from other. Also wanted to know whether it is possible with mobile service .net back end or not?

If any one has any good link or sample project or suggestions then please share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A [repository pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is just a fancy way of saying "I want to work with complex views of the database and/or abstract the database away from the user".  similarly, a [unit of work pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) is just a fancy way of saying "I want to work with transactions".  The [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) is just a fancy way of saying "Separation of concerns".  So, basically, you want an enterprise application (probably mobile) where the user doesn't see the implementation of the database, data layer is separated from business logic and presentation logic and you can support transactions?

Azure Mobile Services and it's successor, [Azure App Service Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/) provide a great way of getting at views of the data - you just set up a view within your database and then Entity Framework can expose that view for you.  it is generally used to expose database tables and there are [plenty of examples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples) in the Azure Samples - including the [FieldEngineer](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-donet-fieldengineer) demo, which provides a concrete example of an enterprise-level mobile application.

You have not provided any details of your application which would indicate design decisions.  Azure App Service and Mobile Apps, at the end of the day, are just APIs on the wire.  They provide a consistent identity and data access layer for the data stored in Azure services.